# Would short 30AWG wires be a problem for 1A pull?

Tags: wire, amperage

My knowledge in electrical engineering is extremely basic. I'm currently doing a project and I'm in the process of choosing the correct wire. My lack of experience is making it hard to know the limits.

The project will have: 18650 battery, TP4056 charging module, MT3608 buck converter, N20 motor (6V from the seller) and some microswitches (1 ampere,) all enclosed in 3D printed plastic. The length of the wires won't exceed 15cm.

I'll be wiring as: 18650 > TP4056 > buck converter (boosting to 9V) > microswitches (a couple wired in DPDT + 1 SPDT + 1 SPST) > N20 motor

From what I could gather from the internet, the N20 maximum current (stall) will be 1A for 12V and if the wire charts I saw were accurate, 28AWG is rated with 1.4A so this would make it ideal. However, wire thickness is something I'd like to keep as thin as possible while still being safe and avoid damaging the components.

Assuming the N20 @9V will pull 1A when stalled, would 30AWG (rated 0.8A) be a big problem? My main concern is safety, it's low voltage but I don't wish to damage the 18650 battery and I'm not running resistors (I assume the charging module and buck converter are already working as resistors but please correct me here.)

Since the wire length is short and ideally the motor won't stall or if it does, it's not for long, I wonder how far I can cut the wire thickness while keeping the project safe for myself and the components.

Comment: Heat energy removal occurs in three mechanisms: conduction, convection, and radiation. Conduction via an insulator into air isn't good. But conduction at the soldered end-points is likely pretty good. So short wires probably benefit there in a way the specifications cannot accommodate. Convection in open air is likely to be no better or worse for long vs short, absent any knowledge about circumstances. Same with radiation. So the place where short wires make a difference will be in conduction at both ends. Wire something up, push current through it, and see? Or is this commercial?

Comment: Note that you would be wise to add a fuse to protect the wire. The battery can source many tens of Amps that will melt your wire in the case of a fault. This might cause fire or other physical damage.

Comment: @jonk This is a simple personal project that if it works, I'll end up sharing with others, hence my safety concern aswell. I'm beginning prototyping soon but wished to buy the wire first and change the design accordingly to the thickness if needed. Guess I'll end up needing to buy more than one gauge and test it, I'll likely start with what I have available (Dupont cables that seem to be 26AWG) and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @Kartman A fuse was definitely not something I was planning on adding, the size presents some challenges to the design unfortunately. However, if I were to add one, the correct placement would be inbetween the battery and charging module connection, correct? Would a 2A micro car fuse be enough for this project? Thank you

Comment: the fuse is sized to protect the wire. you can get fuses physically smaller than an automotive car fuse. You could also use polymer fuses - these are self resetting. Very common in battery packs and other items.

Comment: Will definitely take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a permissive ampacity chart if it says you can run 1.4 A through AWG 28 wire. This would only apply for wire that has good open space around it and maybe high temperature insulation, too. The normal limit would be around 0.2 A or so. Also, 1.4 A through 28 AWG wire will result in substantial voltage drop.

If you let 1 Amp flow through AWG 30 wire for an extended period, the wire will get hot. The insulation may be damaged. If there is anything around the wire that prevents it from cooling off, then the chance of damage is even higher.

I think I would be looking at 24 or even 20 AWG wire. If you do use the thin wire, keep a close eye on it at first and look for signs of overheating or damage to the insulation. If you use high temperature insulation wire (e.g., silicone jacket wire) then the chances of damage are much lower.

Comment: Interesting. The wires will indeed not be in open space, quite the opposite and 0.2A for this scenario is unfortunate.

I will make an effort to design accordingly for 24AWG, although the heat factor still worries me a bit but only testing will tell for sure. The wires will be completely enclosed and some even in direct contact with other wires.

Thank you